# Watch $localStorage for changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, local-storage, ng-storage

I am using the ngStorage modules which can be found here: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

I am setting a lastSeenId in localStorage for a live updating social feed, as this is a hybrid app (Laravel/AngularJS) I can't store it in `$scope`.

My `StatusesController` gets a array or data (or nothing if none to view) ever X seconds and I get the last item of the array and set my `$localStorage` var like this: 
`$localStorage.lastStatusSeen = lastId;`

My navigation controller is where I set some new counters for the user to see if they have missed anything, I am getting lastSeenId like this: 
`$scope.$storage.lastStatusSeen` which gets sent over to my API to return a number of unseen status posts.

This all works, user is on status page, if new data, then set the local storage var to the last ID in the array of data.

The issue is that my `NavigationController` is not finding this change and always passes the `lastSeenId` that was passed when the user first visited the page.

Is there a way to watch that key in local storage for changes?

**EDIT: As requested, updated code**

```
    app.controllers.navigationController = ['$scope', 'pollingService', '$localStorage', function($scope, pollingService, $localStorage) {

    $scope.lastStatusSeen = $localStorage.lastStatusSeen;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $localStorage.lastStatusSeen;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (!newVal) {
            return;
        }

        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            // Assign to a local scoped var, or anything, here...
            $scope.lastStatusSeen = newVal;
            // I suggest call a method to do your logic outside this
            //$scope.onIdChange(newVal, oldVal); // If you need oldVal
        }
    });

    pollingService.startPolling('emailCount', 'api/email/new-count', 5000, function(response) {
        $scope.emailCount = response.data;
    });

    pollingService.startPolling('statusCount', 'api/social/new-count?lastid=' + $scope.lastStatusSeen, 5000, function(response) {
        $scope.socialCount = response.data;
    });

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch it using the `$watch` method of any scope entity of `angular` (`$scope` or `$rootScope`):

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $localStorage.lastStatusSeen;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
       return;
    }

    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        // Assign to a local scoped var, or anything, here...
        // I suggest call a method to do your logic outside this

        $scope.onIdChange(newVal, oldVal); // If you need oldVal
    }
});
```

Be careful with performance because this runs almost every `$digest` cycle. Another note is that you can associate this watcher to a variable, so you can cancel it anytime you need:

```
var watchIdStored = $scope.$watch(function () {
    /* ... */
```

When you want to remove it, call the var as a function:

```
watchIdStored(); // Removes the $watcher
```

## Edit 1:

The problem there is on `pollingService.startPolling('statusCount', 'api/social/new-count?lastid=' + $scope.lastStatusSeen`. It builds up a string that isn't changed anymore. You have to inform this change as it happens, providing to the poll the update.

If you put a console inside the watcher, where you update the var, you'll see that it's updating.

## Edit 2:

As you have a `stopPolling()` method, you can create a build/destroy function on your controller.

```
function _setupPolling (name, url, pollingTime, callback) {
    pollingService.stopPolling(name);

    pollingService.startPolling.apply(pollingService, arguments);
}
```

Now, you call it on every change that occurs on `$localStorage.lastStatusSeen`:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $localStorage.lastStatusSeen;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
        return;
    }

    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal);

        // Assign to a local scoped var, or anything, here...
        $scope.lastStatusSeen = newVal;
        // I suggest call a method to do your logic outside this

        _setupPolling('statusCount', 'api/social/new-count?lastid=' + $scope.lastStatusSeen, 5000, function(response) {
            $scope.socialCount = response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I am doing as your code above suggests, I am assigning it to a scope var put my AJAX call still shows ID 23, when local storage shows 24?

Comment: Question updated, I am placing this in my navigation controller?

Comment: But if I put that pollingService call inside my watcher this will only call that once the ID has been changed? That function polls the server every 5 secs or so?

Comment: Ok, how would I go about updating my service? What method would I need to add, here is my Service code: http://laravel.io/bin/Xyl6j

Comment: Updated the answer. It's more like a paliative. As you already keep one instance, to call `clearInterval` later, you can add one different approach, updating the existent ones in place of deleting it. You choose what fits better...

Comment: Sorry, got distracted! It sure did man, thanks a lot for this, saved me so much headache!